# How to get alert box when i tap marker in map using google_maps_flutter: ^0.2.0 plugin

Tags: flutter

I have used google_maps_flutter: ^0.2.0 plugin to display map. When i tap marker in map, I want to display alert box. I can capture marker event but alert box does not displayed. How to display alert box when i click marker.

```
mapController.onMarkerTapped.add((marker)
    {
      print("Marker Tapped");

       _showDialog();
    });
```

Comment: So you see this print on your log, but the `_showDialog` function isn't showing anything, right? Could you show us the code of the `_showDialog` method?

Comment: void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }